# Validity of a Facebook Page Access Token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

For what duration is a facebook "**page** access token" valid ?

Also, does the facebook "**app** access token" let you post on a page (of which the user is the admin) i.e can we do a Http Post to update a page/users status with the app access token?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook recently removed un-expiring access tokens for users, so long-lived access tokens last 60 days. Short lived ones last two hours.

But it does appear that they are leaving them un-ending for pages.

See the notice on the [deprecation of offline_access](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/), specifically the section on Page Access. Also, take a look at the [server side auth process](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/).

When you go through the server side access, you'll need to request the '[manage_pages](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/#page_perms)' permission.